# I'm trying to transfer a function to node.js project

Tags: c++, node.js-addon

I'm trying to transfer a function to node.js project. I've succeeded in creating the function itself so far. The JavaScript code is accepting it and everything works as it should. I'm not exactly certain on how to pass in any parameters nor return any value. I'm using nan.h for this.

The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <math.h>
#include <nan.h>
// using namespace v8 ;
// using namespace std ;

NAN_METHOD( encript ) {
  const float stringLn = 11 ;

  std::string data = "Hello World" ;
  int bit8Data[ sizeof( data ) / sizeof( data[0] ) ];
  for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i )
  {
    bit8Data[i] = int( long( std::bitset<8>( data.c_str()[i] ).to_ulong()));
  }

  int bit6Data[ 15 ];
  int remainder = 0, remainderLn = 0;
  int j = 0 ;
  for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i )
  {
    if ( remainderLn == 6 ) {
      bit6Data[j] = remainder ;
      j++ ;
      remainder = 0 ;
      remainderLn = 0 ;
    };

    bit6Data[j] = int( remainder * pow( 2, 8 ) + bit8Data[i] ) / int( pow( 2, remainderLn + 2 ));
    remainder   = int( remainder * pow( 2, 8 ) + bit8Data[i] ) % int( pow( 2, remainderLn + 2 ));
    remainderLn += 2 ;

    j++ ;
  }
  if ( remainderLn > 0 ) bit6Data[j] = remainder * ( pow( 2, 6 - remainderLn ));

  for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( bit6Data ) / sizeof( bit6Data[0] ); ++i )
  {
    std::cout << i << ": " << bit6Data[i] << std::endl ;
  }
}


NAN_MODULE_INIT( encriptInit ) {
  Nan::SetMethod( target, "encript", encript );
}

NODE_MODULE( encript, encriptInit );
```

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/main/doc/methods.md#nanfunctioncallbackinfo

Answer (score 0):

`NAN_METHOD` creates a definition with a single `info` parameter that is an array of `Local<Value>`. `info[0]` will be the first one, `info.This()` will be the `this` and you can call `info.Length()` to get the count. Call `info.GetReturnValue().Set(value)` to return a value.